# Jetpack Compose BottomSheetScaffold: Avoid bottom sheet overlapping top bar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I use `BottomSheetScaffold` to set up a view with a `topBar` and some `sheetContent`.

When the bottom sheet is fully expanded, it overlaps the `topBar` (a.k.a. action bar or app bar). Is there a way to ensure that it does not overlap?

[image]

Comment: There was an issue filed for that usecase (if it wasn't actually filed by you): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209825720

Comment: @jns thanks for the link, it was not filed by me. However, I'm not sure this is the same issue. It talks about having an offset from the top of the bottom sheet, not an offset from the top of the screen.

Comment: I think he is talking about this code in `BottomSheetScaffold`:  `.onGloballyPositioned {bottomSheetHeight = it.size.height.toFloat()}`. I basically copied the scaffold composable and added an topOffset parameter, which adjusts the final height. But I don't think thats the solution you are looking for

Comment: How do you make that modalsheet overlap topbar? I want that your problem as solution here.

Comment: @olajide you can check out the source code here: https://github.com/gfroerli/app-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ch/coredump/watertemp/activities/MapActivity.kt

Answer (score 3):

As stated in this issue report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209825720, you can use the screen height and subtract the offset you need, to obtain the height of the bottomSheet

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetTest() {

    val topOffset = 56.dp

    BoxWithConstraints() {
        val sheetHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { constraints.maxHeight.toDp() - topOffset }

        BottomSheetScaffold(
            sheetPeekHeight = 96.dp,
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar {
                    Text(text = "Wassertemperaturen", fontSize = 20.sp)
                }
            },
            sheetContent = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .requiredHeight(sheetHeight)
                        .padding(24.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "OST Badewiese", fontSize = 20.sp)
                    Text("Der beliebte Badeplatz direkt hinter der Hochschule")
                }
            }) {
            Box(Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rapperswil),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(name = "BottomSheetTest")
@Composable
fun PreviewBottomSheetTest() {
    BottomSheetTest()
}
```

[image]